How Duck Hunt works in slow mo
I wanted to know how Duck Hunt works and why it does not work with modern displays.
I found this question Why doesn't Duck Hunt work on plasma or LCD screens? where the answer suspects detecting white area. This is posted 2011. However now we have visual proof that chosen answer is actually correct. Here is a youtube video. 

. I would have liked to post it as a comment but as a new user with 1 reputation I cant comment it so someone with more rep can post this youtube link as a comment there. Reason for choosing this post is because it was first that came from google search.
And sorry for posting posting a question that wasnt really a question. Just wanted to share that info.

I wrote an answer to that question, referencing the video. Check it out: Why doesn't Duck Hunt work on plasma or LCD screens?

@galacticninja's answer on the linked post certainly seems to address the question of this one, so I am closing this as a duplicate.
